# Master Pages over User Controls

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

An interview question someone asked me but I was left stumped.

If you can implement user controls inside a normal aspx page, what is the use of a master page then ?

Comment: If you need to have a common set of controls on all of your pages would you want to copy the control to every page?  No, you would put it in the Master Page once and all other pages would reference it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A master page defines a layout template. You put things like styling and scripts in the master page, then call them in any page derived from that master.

It's a way of being able to split presentation out from functionality, and things you need everywhere can be put in the masterpage.